# How to Concatenate arrays 'n' time in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

The commands:

```
>> mat = magic( 4 );
>> out = cat( 3, mat, mat );
```

concatenate matrix 'mat', along third dimension, 2 time and produce a 4-by-4-by-2 array

how to do this work 'n' time an produce a 4-by-4-by-n array without using loop?

I know this is possible by using a cell array like this:

```
>> out = cat( 3, cellArray{:} );
```

but how to create this cell array? :

```
>> cellArray = {mat, mat, ... , mat};  % n time
```

how to Concatenate arrays n time in matlab ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

If you want a 3-dimensional matrix:

```
mat = magic(4);
n = 3; % Number of times you want to replicate
out = repmat(mat,[1 1 n]);
```

`out` will be a 4x4xn double array.

If you want a cell array you can do this as an additional step:

```
outCell = mat2cell(out,4,4,ones(1,n));
```

`outCell` will be a 1x1xn cell array.

Comment: @HamedHamed: You can simply call `repmat({mat},[1,1,n])` if the output should be a cell array.